# Change of coordinates of the blow-up

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I try to compute the change of coordinate of the blow-up, using the notation of 'Principles of algebraic geometry' by Griffiths and Harris on page 184. My problems are in the first steps, defining the inverse of the chart: Let $\tilde{U} = \{ (z,l) \in \mathbb{C}^{n} \times \mathbb{P}^{n-1} \mid z_{i}l_{j} = z_{j}l_{i} \; \forall i,j = 0, \dots, n \}$ and $\tilde{U}_{i} = \tilde{U} \setminus \{ (l_{i} = 0) \}$, then $(\tilde{U}_{i},\varphi_{i})$ is a coordinate subset and the charts are given by
$$
\varphi_{i}: \tilde{U}_{i} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{n}, (z, l) \mapsto (z(i)_{1}, \dots, z(i)_{i}, \dots, z(i)_{n})
$$
But what is with the inverse? Is it only
$$
(t_{1}, \dots, t_{n}) \mapsto ((t_{1}, \dots, t_{n}),l) \; ?
$$
And when this is true, the change of coordinates ($i < j$) is
$$
\varphi_{j} \circ \varphi_{i}^{-1}(t_{1}, \dots, t_{n}) = \Big(\frac{t_{1}}{t_{j}}, \dots, \frac{t_{i}}{t_{j}}, \dots, \frac{t_{j}}{t_{j}}, \dots, \frac{t_{n}}{t_{j}}\Big) \; ?
$$
I'm a little bit irritated because of this notation and I'm not sure with this change of coordinates. Is it possible to write this with the $t_{i}$ or $z(i)_{j}$? Thanks for help.

Comment: It seems right to me.

Comment: @Luca Thanks for your comment. So when I understand this mapping in the right way, then you have two times the number 1: $t_{i}/t_{j} = 1$ and $t_{j}/t_{j} = 1$. Equivalently you can write the change of coordinates, for example, $(\frac{t(i)_{1}}{t(i)_{j}}, \dots, \frac{1}{t(j)_{i}}, \dots, t(i)_{i}t(i)_{j}, \dots, \frac{t(i)_{n}}{t(i)_{j}})$. At the places $i$ and $j$, you can vary with the depiction of the 1 ?!